# Could I send \timing to postgres via libpq?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I want to obtain query's execution time like \timing shows, but it seems there is no effect I send the command by PQexec(), is there any other approach can I obtain a query's execution time ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\timing` is a client-side command implemented in `psql`. It reports the time from when `psql` sends the query to when it receives the response. Take a look at the `psql` source code for details.

It isn't possible to do that on the server side.

You probably want `log_min_duration_statement`, `client_min_messages`, `log_duration`, `explain (analyze on, costs off, timing on)`, etc if you want server-side timing.

Most likely though, you just want to save the wallclock time before you run the query and compare it to the wallclock time at the end of the query in your client.